# Copy Rows (Not CurrentRegion) from Activecell Until Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to find activecell and copy current region. But I need to copy entire rows instead.

[image: Picture(Target)]

Existing code:

```
Sub findRange(valueToFind)

    Dim ra As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set ra = xlSheet.Cells.Find(What:=valueToFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    True, SearchFormat:=False)

    lastRow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ra.CurrentRegion.Copy _
    Destination:=DestSheet.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: ra is returning first match. ra.EntireRow that whole row. ra.CurrentRegion contiguous region around that cell (i.e. upto white space). You can use resize on ra with .EntireRow to get a specified number of rows.

Comment: I got a workaround by specify a large number of columns, say 100.

Comment: But I still don't know how to do the entire rows yet.

Comment: .EntireRow is how you get the entire row. Range("A1").EntireRow is entire row so if find returns A1 put .EntireRow on the end of the variable you assign the find result to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly if this is what you're trying to accomplish, but:

- `ActiveCell` is the current cell
- `ActiveCell.End(xlDown)` is the cell you would go to if you pressed End Down, meaning, the last occupied cell below the current cell
- `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))` is the range between those

Since you said you want entire rows you need

```
  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).EntireRow
```

Try

```
  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Select
```

to see if this is actually what you want; if so, replace the `.Select` with `.Copy`

Comment: Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Select selected rows at sheet1 where I run script.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentRegion returns a Range object that represents a set of contiguous data. As long as the data is surrounded by one empty row and one empty column.
This should get you what you need.

```
Sub findRange(valueToFind)

Dim ra As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set DestSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")

Set ra = xlSheet.Cells.Find(What:=valueToFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
True, SearchFormat:=False)

lastRow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

StartRow = ra.CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Row 'gets the starting row of you current region
RegionRowCount = ra.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'counts the number of rows in your current region
    'StartRow + RegionRowCount - 1 is used to get the last row of the CurrentRegion, -1 is because we counted the first row
xlSheet.Rows(StartRow & ":" & StartRow + RegionRowCount - 1).Copy _
Destination:=DestSheet.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Rows(StartRow & ":" & StartRow + RegionRowCount - 1).Copy copied info from the sheet where I ran script. I need to find out how to refer to the rows i want to copy from. There are three sheets in the script.

Comment: See edit to answer.  Added your xlSheet reference to rows().copy

Answer (score 0):

Really appreciate all the help!!! Never used VBA before. It gave me confidence to continue. Thanks very much.

There must be several ways to solve the problem. I am ok with currentregion-offset-resize.

```
Sub findRange(valueToFind)

Dim ra As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim StartRow As Long, RegionRowCount As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set DestSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")

lastRow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set ra = xlSheet.Cells.Find(What:=valueToFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
True, SearchFormat:=False)

ra.CurrentRegion.Resize(, 100).Copy _
Destination:=DestSheet.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It works. but not the direct answer to the original question